# Executing coverity scan on go project

Tags: go, coverity

Coverity version: 2020.09

go version go1.14.15

Coverity build command

cov-build --dir coverity_dir go build source.go

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.

Comment: This warning message is not enough . Please go through the files are getting executing in cov-build.if the files are getting invoked by the configured compiler ,you can see prints starts with EXECUTING in build-log.txt

Comment: Also make sure if you native build is clean